# How to deploy a java webapp created in eclipse by spring mvc

Tags: eclipse, spring, deployment

I created a web app in eclipse by spring m v c and it run smoothly with eclipse run as server on a p ache tomcat and i also created a .war file in tomcat/web app. but i want ask that how i deploy this app for use on other computer and run on those computer without eclipse and J D K .(e.g.) as just my friend wants to use this app on his computer only with install J RE and how i deploy app for giving him for his use in easy way.
  please please any one can tell me how?
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only 2 options:

1) Let your friend install some servlet container. Eg. Apache tomcat. Then you simply put your war inside it's webaps directory and run tomcat.

2) Embedd your own servlet container into war (this is called executable war). The simples Spring way is to use Spring boot.

Comment: Tanks Kulatamicuda, i put war file in webapp directory of tomcat and application work fine but i want to make it a installer pakage as any on can use it on his pc

Comment: You can use Install4J for making installations. But it is commercial application. Free alternative could be embedded servlet (Spring boot) and http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/ , but it is more complex to help you here (and in fact it is an another question). Please make my answer to "answered" state to help show others that this question was answered.

Comment: Brother i want to create a .exe package of my web app as joget workflow and Alfresco made of there web app in nullsoft installer system. and i also want to this but not know how to this.plz chek these applications

Comment: @Rehan I do not understand. If you have another question feel free to ask new question on stack overflow.